# Join two functions JqueryUI datepicker for "beforeShowDay"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Thank you so much for taking the time to read. I have a calendar that allows booking and selecting dates, but I need to disable specific weekdays, months, but also third friday or second tuesday for certain trips. So I have this functions that @Thierry J. helped me to clean up, but i need to join it to the last function (activate only third friday, or second tuesday, and so on).

```
var daysToDisable = [1, 4, 6];
var monthsToDisable = [9];

function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }
    return [true];
}
```

To activate only third friday for the selected months I have this function:

```
var day = date.getDay();
var date = date.getDate();
return [(day == 5 && date >= 15 && date <= 21), ''];
```

So I was wondering if is possible to have all those functions together for beforeShowDay, but with the ability to select the trips that will have those restrictions. The "days to disable", and "months to disable" functions are ready and work with this variables:

```
var daysToDisable = [1, 4, 6];
var monthsToDisable = [9];
```

And i'll like to have the possibility to disable in the same way the specific week days:

```
var specificdaysToDisable = []
```

Also if there is a much better possibility to code it, so i'll be able to deactivate third friday for one trip, second tuesday for a different one, then i'm open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make a fiddle of out and share the fiddle.

Comment: Sure, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/MJ87G/ 

This fiddle doesn't has yet the possibility to disable the third friday every month. Thanks!

Comment: Like this code is working for you http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/MJ87G/2/ ?

Comment: Can you elaborate how specificdaysToDisable do you want to work?

Comment: The fiddle you just sent me deactivates third, instead of deactivating all the others and leaving third friday active, but also will be great if it's possible to have a variable to deactivate for certain trips only, something like: var specialfridayToEnable = [ true or a # ]; 

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, take a look to this, better? http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/MJ87G/4/ elaborate better specialfridayToEnable please

Comment: Sure. specialfridayToEnable will be a variable only to activate the funtion. I have for example three trips, each one has it's specific weekdays and months to disable, but only one of them will have the specialfridayToEnable variable active. 

So each trip has two variables: var daysToDisable = [ # ]; var monthsToDisable = [ #]; 

But in the case of the third trip it needs three: var daysToDisable = [ #]; var monthsToDisable = [#]; varspecialfridayToEnable = [1(true)]

Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this will be the final code, but also I'm open to suggestions as I'm not sure if it's syntax is correct or if there could be other ways to improve the code.

Also in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amatoro/yFtLP/) and with [short version with inArray var](http://jsfiddle.net/amatoro/yFtLP/1/).

```
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths,
});

var daysToDisable = [0, 2, 3, 4, 6];
var monthsToDisable = [1, 2 ];
var specificDaysToDisable = [5];

function disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    } 

    var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var date2 = date.getDate();
    if ($.inArray(day, specificDaysToDisable) != -1 && date2 <= 14 || $.inArray(day, specificDaysToDisable) != -1 && date2 >= 22 ) {
        return [false];
    }
    return [true]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To know if is the third week instead of check the day is not between 14 and 22, you can write your own `Date.prototype.getWeekOfMonth` function to get the week number of the month and than use it to check the condition.

Code:

```
Date.prototype.getWeekOfMonth = function(exact) {
    var month = this.getMonth()
        , year = this.getFullYear()
        , firstWeekday = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()
        , lastDateOfMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
        , offsetDate = this.getDate() + firstWeekday - 1
        , index = 1 // start index at 0 or 1, your choice
        , weeksInMonth = index + Math.ceil((lastDateOfMonth + firstWeekday - 7) / 7)
        , week = index + Math.floor(offsetDate / 7)
    ;
    if (exact || week < 2 + index) return week;
    return week === weeksInMonth ? index + (weeksInMonth -1 ) : week;
};

jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths,
});

var daysToDisable = [0, 2, 3, 4, 6];
var monthsToDisable = [1, 2];
var specificDaysToDisable = [5];

function disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths(date) {

    var day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var date2 = date.getDate();
    var inArray = $.inArray(day, specificDaysToDisable)
    if (inArray != -1 && date.getWeekOfMonth()!=3) {
        return [false];
    }
    return [true]
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/yFtLP/11/

Comment: This conditional if (day != 5 || date2 < 15 || date2 > 21) deactivates all the days, so if I need mondays active for that trip, then i won't be able to do it. Please have in mind that var daysToDisable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6] it's only an example. So if I try with the real ones: var daysToDisable = [0, 2, 4, 6]

Monday and wednesday will be inactive too

Comment: Got it, rebuild the answer from the start try to check it

Comment: Thank you so much @Edward, even if my code was working, your code is definitely much better than mine. I'll change it. But also I was wondering. If for example this trip will have friday of the third week deactivated, but if there is a trip that needs to have friday but week number 2 or 1, is there a variable to select the week to deactivate for each, instead of third week for all?

I wonder if this will be enough or it could generate errors? http://jsfiddle.net/amatoro/yFtLP/4/ 

But also what happens to the months that have 5 weeks?, try: var weektoEnable = [5]

Thanks again!

Comment: PLease replace this line to solve the 5 weeks months bug:

`return week === weeksInMonth ? index + 5 : week;`

with this: `return week === weeksInMonth ? index + (weeksInMonth -1 )  : week;`